# PHP - Regex - Validation for name field - Detect if user enters '&' or 'and'

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation, preg-match

I am trying to use regex to detect when a user enters something like "Bob & Jane" or "Bob and Jane".

I have tried the following and all of them are trigged when something like "andy" or "andrew" are entered:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]( & | and )[a-zA-Z]$/

/(" "and" "|" "&" ")/

/( and | & )/
```

(I tried all these with and without the `'^'` and `'$'`)

Thank you in Advanced for you thoughts!

Comment: Use `and\b` to match the word and when the character after it causes a word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

The second approach seems good but the quotes confuse the regex engine. Use whitespace token instead:

```
/[a-z]+(\sand\s|\s&\s)[a-z]+/
```

Comment: That wouldn't detect `Bob & Jane`.

Comment: This is just for `and` or `&` part, obviously.

Comment: No. Before the edit, it [wouldn't have detected](https://eval.in/164922) `Bob & Jane`. Now it should, though. And the regex can be just `\b\s*(&|and)\s*\b` — [see demo](http://regex101.com/r/yB5lD0).

Comment: These all seem to be triggered upon 'andy' or 'andrea' being enterd.

Answer (score 2):

What part of the expression do you wish to capture?

```
(\&|\band\b)
```

will not look for whitespace, but will look for either the `&` symbol OR `and` which is broken apart by some kind of word boundary (like whitespace) ([live example](http://regex101.com/r/jO2zJ8)).

You might see the code for this as:

```
$re = '/(\&|\band\b)/mi'; 
$str = 'Bob & Jane\nBob and Jane\nAndy and Andrew\nFrank Anderson & Michael\nWhere is Waldo && Carmen Sandiego and Crew & Oliver and Company\n'; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

If you wish to capture the names themselves, you can always expand this, although names are [very hard to define](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) easily.

Answer (score 1):

I would personnaly use:

```
/^\w+\s(&|and)\s\w+$/
```

This way you don't have to repeat the spaces around the & / and.